# AppsScript for Google Docs - How do I add / edit / delete Variable Smart Chips in Google Docs programmatically with appsscript addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-apps-script-api

AppsScript for Google Docs - How do I add / edit / delete Variable Smart Chips in Google Docs programmatically with appsscript addon?

New Variable Smart Chips feature for Google Docs Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13584275?hl=en
AppsScript API Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getbody

Google Workspace Release 2023-06-05 Info: https://support.google.com/a/table/7314896?hl=en#query=variable

Comment: That's not supported yet in Apps Script.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the feature you're looking for isn't available. The latest update for Google Apps Script has to do with third-party smart chips, and link previews are now generally available. The details can be found in the [Google Apps Script release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes#June_12_2023).

As it turns out, this request has already been submitted by multiple users, and I've upvoted it, since I think it would be a great feature. If you have the time, it would be great if you could upvote as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225584757

### Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes